# Mongoose - Protect the password field depending on the requested route

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Given the following user model:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: Number,
  userID: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  userName: String,
  password: {type: String, select: false}, 
  isAdministrator: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});
```

This model ensures that the password is not returned in the event of a request.

**How do I change the UserModel so that the password is returned for Route A and not for Route B?**

For instance:

```
router.get('/A', [returns password])
router.get('/B', [returns no password])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, where you execute your Mongoose Query,
for example:

```
User.findOne({email})
```

you append a select function and put inside the parethesis the field you want to be selected, for instance:

```
User.findOne({email}).select("+password")
```

If you put a "-" it will exclude the field, if you do not put any symbol it will select that field, the "+" forces the selection of the fields that have a "select false" property defined in the schema.

[Query.prototype.select() documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-select)